# x and y axis nonlinear error fit possible?

Tags: fitting, nonlinear

I have a set of datapoints with x (position) errors as well as y (measurement) errors. Is there a way in Mathematica to fit a nonlinear function through this points, with weighting both, the x and y errors?

Comment: Please post your datapoints. Also this might help you https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KolZZm8If9Q

Comment: Unfortunately the video didnt help, it just shows normal nonlinear fitting, I need it with the weighting of x and y errors though.

Comment: This has been asked a number of times already on this site. For example: [(13054)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13054/), [(33273)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/33273/), [(27101)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/27101/linear-regression-with-x-and-y-errors) (there are surely others). Basically, the linear case can be done somewhat straightforwardly, but nonlinear is more difficult mathematically. I suggest you proceed with it as a minimization problem. It has been demonstrated in [(24788)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/24788/).