# Efficiency problem with least square algorithm (Error in both variables)

Tags: performance-tuning, fitting

I was informing myself about the least square algorithms with errors in `x` and `y`. I found [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13054/estimate-error-on-slope-of-linear-regression-given-data-with-associated-uncertai) and the top answer wasn't working for magnitudes around `10^-20`. Because I couldn't figure out why, I completed the code from belisarius to also produce errors on slope and intercept. But my code is really, really slow, if I take `10` or more `{x, y}` pairs with errors it takes way too long. I think it's the [`Reduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Reduce.html) part that slows it down so much, but I don't know how to make it more efficient. Also the function output isn't really elegant yet.

```
LinFit[xi_List, yi_List, errx_List, erry_List]:=
  Module[{n=Length@xi,wi,ui,vi,wmean,d,g,a,b,set,least,c,wxi,wyi},
  wxi=errx^-2;
  wyi=erry^-2;
  wi[i_,m_]:=wxi[[i]] wyi[[i]]/(m^2 wyi[[i]]+wxi[[i]]);
  ui[i_,m_]:=xi[[i]]-wmean[xi,m];
  vi[i_,m_]:=yi[[i]]-wmean[yi,m];
  wmean[q_List,m_]:=Sum[wi[i,m] q[[i]],{i,n}]/Sum[wi[i,m],{i,n}];
  d[m_]:=Sum[wi[i,m]^2 ui[i,m]^2/wxi[[i]],{i,n}];
  g[m_]:=-Sum[wi[i,m] ui[i,m] vi[i,m],{i,n}]/d[m];
  a[m_]:=2 Sum[wi[i,m]^2 ui[i,m] vi[i,m]/wxi[[i]],{i,n}]/(3 d[m]);
  b[m_]:=(Sum[wi[i,m]^2 vi[i,m]^2/wxi[[i]],{i,n}]-Sum[wi[i,m] ui[i,m]^2{i,n}])/(3d[m]);

  set={ToRules@Reduce[\[FormalM]^3-3 a[\[FormalM]] \[FormalM] \[FormalM]+
        3 b[\[FormalM]] \[FormalM]-g[\[FormalM]]==0&&\[FormalC]==wmean[yi,\[FormalM]]-
        \[FormalM]wmean[xi,\[FormalM]]&&\[FormalA]==Sqrt[1/(n-2) Sum[wi[i,\[FormalM]]
        ( \[FormalM] ui[i,\[FormalM]]-vi[i,\[FormalM]])^2,{i,n}]/
        Sum[wi[i,\[FormalM]] ui[i,\[FormalM]]^2,{i,n}]]&&\[FormalB]==Sqrt[(
        Sum[wi[i,\[FormalM]] xi[[i]]^2,{i,n}]/Sum[wi[i,\[FormalM]],{i,n}])*
        \[FormalA]^2],{\[FormalM],\[FormalC],\[FormalA],\[FormalB]}, 
        Backsubstitution->True]};
  least=Sum[wxi[[i]] (xi[[i]]-(yi[[i]]-\[FormalC])/\[FormalM])^2+wyi[[i]] (yi[[i]]-
           (\[FormalM] xi[[i]]+\[FormalC]))^2,{i,Length@xi}]/.set[[Flatten@Position[
           \[FormalM]/.set,_Real]]];
  c=Flatten@set[[Flatten@Position[\[FormalM]/.set,_Real]]][[Position[
      least,Min@least][[1]]]];
  {Function[(\[FormalM]/.c[[1]])#+\[FormalC]/.c[[2]]][x],
      {\[FormalA]/.c[[3]],\[FormalB]/.c[[4]]}}
]
```

Comment: Without formatting this is rather unreadable; in the present form I would suggest to ask a machine, not a human being... :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"worals" is an acronym for Weighted Orthogonal Regression by Alternating Least Squares.
Arguments: `x` and `y` are lists of measured values,
`sx` and `sy` are lists of the corresponding standard errors of measurement.
The returned values are `{chisquare, {intercept, slope}}`.

```
worals[x_, y_, sx_, sy_] := Block[{a,b,f,z, u = 1/sx, v = 1/sy, w = (sy/sx)^2},
{a,b} = (y*v).PseudoInverse@{v,x*v}; f = #.#&[(a+b*x-y)v];
While[f > (z = (x*w + (y-a)b)/(b^2 + w);
           {a,b} = (y*v).PseudoInverse@{v,z*v};
           f = #.#&@Join[(z-x)u,(a+b*z-y)v])];
{f,{a,b}}]
```

If the true relation is linear, and if the errors are independent normal with zero means and standard deviations as given in `sx` & `sy`, (or, more to the point, if the foregoing are not too far from truth) then the returned `chisquare` will have a Chi-Square distribution with `n-2` degrees of freedom, where `n = Length@x`. The corresponding p-value is `GammaRegularized[(n-2)/2, chisquare/2]`.

EDIT, responding to questions.

The model is `{x = z + d, y = a + b*z + e}`, where `d` & `e` are random errors, and `a`, `b`, & `z` are unknowns for which values are to be found that minimize the weighted sum of squares `f = #.# & @ Join[(z-x)/sx,(a+b*z-y)/sy]`. We start with `z = x`, then minimize `f` alternately with respect to either `{a,b}` or `z` with the other held constant, until `f` no longer changes.

To estimate the error in `{a,b}`, I usually jackknife the solution:

```
n = Length@x; {f,ab} = worals[x,y,sx,sy];
{jab,jc} = {ab + (n-1)(ab-Mean@#), (n-1)^2/n Covariance@#}& @
           Table[Last[worals@@(Delete[#,i]&/@{x,y,sx,sy})],{i,n}]
```

`jab` is the jackknifed estimate of `{a,b}`, and `jc` is the jackknifed estimate of its covariance matrix; `Sqrt@Diagonal@jc` gives the estimates of the two standard errors.

Comment: Thanks, but I have still trouble understanding how this algorithm works. Could you tell me how i can evaluate the error on slope and intercept in a similar way.

Comment: There is a syntax error in the `While` statement, which needs `test` and `body` separated by a comma.