# Plotting error bars in both dimensions for straight line model

Tags: plotting, fitting

I want to fit a straight line model of the form $y_i = a+ b\ x_i$ to the list of $(x, y)$ pairs given below. How can I plot the data with error bars in both coordinates?

```
Fit[
  {{-5, -1.22}, {-4, -3.28}, {-3, -2.52}, {-2, 3.74}, {-1, 3.01}, {0, -1.8}, {1, 2.49}, 
   {2, 5.48}, {3, 0.42}, {4, 4.80}, {5,4.22}}, 
  {1, x}, {x}
]
```

The data have Gaussian distributed errors in both the $x$
and $y$ coordinates with $\sigma_x = 1$ and $\sigma_y = 2$.

The code gives a straight line fitted for the data. However, I cant plot the error bars from the data. Can anyone help please?

Comment: How are your defining error bars for the $x$'s?  The regression is conditional on the fixed $x$'s and there are no error bars for the $x$'s.  Or do you just want to run $y_i=a+b x_i + error_i$ *and* $x_i = c+d y_i + error_i$ ?

Comment: The data have Gaussian distributed errors in both the $x$
and $y$ coordinates with $\sigma_x = 1$ and $\sigma_y = 2$.

Comment: @jhon_wick This makes the situation quite a bit more complicated. For starters, the linear regression methods available to `Fit` etc assume no error in the independent variable. You will want to take a look at the following older discussion: [Estimate error on slope of linear regression given data with associated uncertainty](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13054/27951). Even then, those answers assume that you know the *values* of the uncertainties associated with the measurements that you are trying to fit, not just their distribution.

Comment: You might want to look up errors-in-variables:  (1) http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/137095/intuitive-meaning-of-error-in-variables and (2) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Errors-in-variables_models.

Comment: And this very recent post might also be helpful:  http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/201859/fitting-a-line-in-r-when-the-independent-variable-has-been-measured-with-known-e.