# Fitting Data when both Variables Have Uncertainties

Tags: fitting, warning-messages, data

Does there exist a method in Mathematica for fitting some function f(x; a, b)=y (with parameters a, b) to data of the form {x, y} when both x and y have different uncertainties?
It seems like it would be a common enough problem, but I cant seem to find an easy way in Mathematica for doing this.
Thanks!

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13054/7167).  A built in function is not available at this time.

Comment: Is the model linear or nonlinear? The latter case is way more difficult.